# Does the equality $\mathbf{x^TBy}=\mathbf{y^TB^Tx}$ always hold?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Suppose we have three matrices $\mathbf{x,y}$, and $\mathbf{B}$. Where $\mathbf{x,y}$ are column vectors of length $n$ and $m$ respectively and size of $\mathbf{B}$ is $n\times m$. In this case $$\mathbf{x^TBy}$$ is a scalar quantity and similarly $$\mathbf{y^TB^Tx}$$ is also a scalar quantity. Is it always true that $$\mathbf{x^TBy}=\mathbf{y^TB^Tx}?$$ or there are some strict conditions under which this can be true?

Comment: If you are talking about matrices over fields, then yes, they are always equal. If, however, the elements of these matrices belong to a non-commutative ring, the equality is no longer assured.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The transpose of a scalar is equals to itself:
$$x^TBy=\sum_{i,j}x_{i}B_{ij}y_{j}$$
And
$$y^TB^Tx=\sum_{i,j}y_i(B^T)_{ij}x_j=\sum_{i,j}y_iB_{ji}x_j=\sum_{i,j}x_jB_{ji}y_i$$
And they are the same.

Comment: thank you for your answer. This also means that $\mathbf{x^TB_1B_2\cdots B_ky}$ is also equal to $\mathbf{y^TB_k^T\cdots B_1^Tx}$ (I am assuming that the dimensions of $\mathbf{B_l}$'s are such that the multiplication is possible). What do you say?

Comment: Yes. For example, in the case of $2$ matrices: $x_iA_{ij}B_{jk}y_k$, and it's transpose is $y_iB_{ji}A_{kj}x_{k}=xABy$. And you can do the same for as many matrices as you want.

Comment: thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

Yes because for any matrices $A$ and $B$ such that the product $AB$ is defined, the product ${}^{\mathrm{t}\!}B\:{}^{\mathrm{t}\mkern-6mu}A$ is too and we have
$${}^{\mathrm{t}\mkern-2mu}(\mkern-1muAB)={}^{\mathrm{t}\!}B\:{}^{\mathrm{t}\mkern-6mu}A.$$

Comment: is there a specific reason for writing the transpose in this special way?

Comment: and perhaps we should also emphasize that the product must be symmetric. Which is true in this case because we have a scalar. Right

Comment: It's just another notation for the transpose. Nothing special. Some people also use $x'$

Comment: @FrankMoses not really, just some notation conventions in several books/countries

Comment: @FrankMoses: it's the way I learnt it when I was student: a prescript lowercase roman t. The LaTeX package `leftidx` defines a command for this notation.

Comment: so its the same thing as the usual transpose. I thought maybe it had some special property.